# XArray apply function to the coordinates

Tags: python-xarray

How do I create a data array by applying a function over the values of the coordinates of a XArray Dataset?

Ex.

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
    coords={
        'x': [1.5, 4, 2],
        'y': [2, -3, -1],
    },
)
# some function like *apply that takes the coordinates as a list?
r = ds.apply*(lambda coords: math.sqrt(coords.x**2 + coords.x**2))
```

Should output

```
r = 2.5, 5, 2.6..
```